# how get states with API in another component in react native

Tags: react-native

I want get my polygons in fetch.js and convert to usable format and use that in OpenStreetMap.js but I dont know how return data or use component state in sibling component and I dont want use redux.

fetch.js

```
  getData() {
   fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {this.setState({polygons:data})})
    .catch(error => console.log(error));}
```

OpenStreetMap.js

```
 <MapView
        region={this.state.region}
        provider={null}
        style={styles.map} >
         {this.state.polygons.map(polygon => (
           <Polygon
            key={polygon.id}
            coordinates={polygon.coordinates}
            strokeColor={polygon.strokeColor}
            fillColor={polygon.fillColor}
            strokeWidth={2}
          />
         ))}
      </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm you might want to use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) in your `fetch.js`, this will return a promise. Call this in your constructor then do a setState.

in `fetch.js`

```
export default async function getData(key) {
  try {
    let value = await fetch("url");
    return value.json();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("caught error", e);
    return {};
    // Handle exceptions
  }
}
```

`OpenStreetMap.js`

```
import getData from "./fetch";
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {};
   getData().then((data) => {
     this.setState({polygons:data});
   });
}
```

Or other option is send a callback function and get the data back, and do a setState.
For Example

```
export default async function getData(callback) {
fetch('url')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {callback(data)})
  .catch(error => console.log(error));}
```

then in your `OpenStreetMap.js`

```
import getData from "./fetch";
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {};
   getData(this.getPolygonData);
}

getPolygonData = (data) => {
  this.setState({polygons:data});
}
```

Here's working example https://snack.expo.io/@subkundu/rude-milkshake

Comment: thank. but my problem is  return data from fetch.js and import that in openstreet.js

Comment: umm, you needed to export the function. I updated the answer with a working example.

Comment: Perfect. Accept the answer by clicking on the left side check.